# Running same jenkins.war from different hosts

Tags: jenkins

We have a planned server shutdown. So we are moving our activities to another server temporarily. We have a jenkins running in our current server. All the jenkins source files and workspace are in shared path. I tried running the same jenkins.war in the new host and now I have the exact replica there with all the jobs and history. Once we get our original machine back, hoping we will get all the jobs and artifacts created in the mean time(in the temp host), once I start the jenkins from our original machine. Can you please let me know whether is it safe. Are there any risks in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jenkins configurations / workspace are setup in such a way so that they can easily be moved to another jenkins installation. Since you are using a shared path for configurations, the same concept of using those configurations for multiple jenkins instances should apply, only with more ease of setup since you don't have to move the files. In short, there shouldn't be any risk in pointing to those files from a different jenkins installation, as long as both installations aren't running at the same time. Of course, you should always back up your configurations, regardless.